# Really weird react-native image issue

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I have an avatar component...
Which returns this...

```
return (
    <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center',marginTop:-10}}>
        <Image source={{uri: this.state.avatar}} />
        <Text style={styles.profileHeader}>
            {this.state.username} 
        </Text>
    </View>
    )
```

I then am using this avatar by passing the username and avatar as props.
This works fine...

```
   return (
        <View>
          <AvatarHeader   username={d.test_username} avatar={d.test_avatar} />
        </View>     
    );
```

Now for the weird part.
If I do this...

```
   return (
        <View>
          <Image source={{uri: d.test_avatar}}  />
          <AvatarHeader   username={d.test_username} avatar={d.test_avatar} />
        </View>     
    );
```

The Image doesn't display.  The AvatarHeader still displays, but the Image wont.
Even though in the AvatarHeader, its literally the exact same image URL being passed.

(And yes, I AM including 'Image' as a require on the main page)

Comment: In the component you mean this: `this.props.avatar` instead of this `this.state.avatar` , right ?

Comment: yes, you are correct.  That was just a typo on here though.  Its props in the code......But  I ended up solving this issue by adding style={{width:50, height:50}} to the image.  Then it worked.  Strange that I didn't need styling on the AvatarHeader Image tag, and needed it on the Image one.  Don't really understand why either.  Maybe something to do with the flex:1 in the View of the AvatarHeader.  And the Image was wrapped in a View with no styling?

Answer (score 1):

I too found out something weird using react-native - realized what is wrong.

When you import an image as a file, the image will show no problem (without setting its size) for example:

```
<Image source = {require('./img.jpeg')}/>
```

However if you set the image source from a uri, then the image will not show unless you set the image size on stylesheet.

```
<Image source = {{uri: this.state.uri}}/>
```

The reason is that when the image is imported, the size comes with it.
but when you use uri, the size is undefined.